# UDP socket in web browser?

Tags: sockets, web, browser, udp

I'm trying to find information about this, but with no success.

Is it possible to open a UDP socket in a (any?) browser from my website?

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't have any API's that let you create UDP sockets. In fact, it doesn't even allow you to create TCP sockets and communicate using arbitrary protocols.

What you can do however is use WebSockets or another communication method that can be done from the browser, and have a proxy server somewhere that sends the actual UDP packets. Other than that, no browser currently lets you create UDP sockets from Javascript.

Comment: My site already uses websockets, but for a different purpose. This breaks my heart </3